# Sort List by Value of SubList with where clause LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have a object structure like so

```
public class Obj1
   {
      public string Name {get; set;}
      public List<KeyValuePair<int, double>> PairList {get; set;}
   }
```

If I have a list of Obj1, how would I be able to Order that list based on the largest value in Pair list, where key is a particular value. For instance this object.

```
       List<Obj1> foo = new List<Obj1>()
            {
                new Obj1()
                {
                    Name = "Foo",
                     PairList = new List<KeyValuePair<int, double>>()
                     {
                         new KeyValuePair<int, double>(1,20),
                         new KeyValuePair<int, double>(2,25),
                         new KeyValuePair<int, double>(3,30)
                     }
                },
                    new Obj1()
                {
                        Name = "Bar",
                     PairList = new List<KeyValuePair<int, double>>()
                     {
                         new KeyValuePair<int, double>(1,20),
                         new KeyValuePair<int, double>(2,60),
                         new KeyValuePair<int, double>(3,30)
                     }
                },
                        new Obj1()
                {
                        Name = "Test",
                     PairList = new List<KeyValuePair<int, double>>()
                     {
                         new KeyValuePair<int, double>(1,20),
                         new KeyValuePair<int, double>(2,35),
                         new KeyValuePair<int, double>(3,30)
                     }
                }
            };
```

If I want to order by the above list where the Key is 2, I would expect the order of the list to be the following names

```
Bar
Test
Foo
```

How can I do this in LINQ?

Comment: Just curious, why the `List<KVP<key, value>>` instead of `Dictionary<key,value>`?  Are you concerned about duplicated keys or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
var result= foo.OrderByDescending(x => x.PairList[1].Value);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to take the *max* value from `PairList` and uset it to sort the objects by it.

```
var result = foo.OrderByDescending(x => x.PairList.Max(v => v.Value));
```